# Apache as a Reverse Proxy Exposes internal server strings

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, reverse-proxy

I'm using Apache mod_proxy as a reverse proxy to internal servers, with mod_security to rename the apache server string to something different, however the server string of the internal servers get forwarded instead. Obviously I want my reverse-proxy to hide the Server String of the internal servers (can't change them directly) and instead show the custom one.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

`mod_headers` is able to manipulate the `Server` header in proxy responses.

```
Header set Server foo
```